# My selected field does not fill correctly with the fat-free framework

Tags: php, vue.js, dropdown

I am confronting a problem trying to fill my select field with the fat-free framework.

I try to use axios as in most tutorial, I point to "response.data" but nothing fills in my field.

I have this code in my model:

```
public function ReadUserData($action) {
    if (strcmp($action, "read") == 0) {
        global $f3;
        $user = $this->db->exec("SELECT * FROM users");
        return json_encode($user);
    }
}
```

I have this in my controller:

```
$Users = new UserModel($this->db);
$DataUser = $Users->ListDatabaseUser();
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
  $data = $Users->ReadUserData($_GET['action']);
  $f3->set("users", $data);
}
```

and in vue js I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Myapp = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  delimiters: ['{%', '%}'],
  data: {
    heading: 'test',
    dataSelect: null,
    makes_options: []
  },
  created() {
    axios.get('http://localhost/?action=read')
    .then(function(response) {
          Myapp.make_options = response.data;
          console.log(Myapp.make_options);
      });
  }
});
```

I also try to replace:

`Myapp.make_options = "{{ @users }}"` but without sucess :/

For display that I have this in html:

```
<label for="Select">Select</label>
<select class="form-control" name="dataSelect" id="dataSelect" v-model="dataSelect">
  <option v-for="option in makes_options" :value="option.id">{% option.username %}</option>
</select>
```

Currently my field is empty and I do not understand why my json is not interpreted correctly

Comment: `makes_options` in data and `Myapp.make_options` missing an `s`. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried checking where the problem occurs? Is all data sent to the backend, as expected (which would make the `vue.js` tag obsolet) - or is data aggregation your problem (which would make the `php` tag obsolet)?

Comment: yes than'ks i add the "s" but in console.log of "Myapp.makes_options" I have an array. The display does not mean it's really weird, my select is running with the same number as in my base but nothing is displayed in it.